# CUDA Nsight Exceptions ("DataStackOverflow")

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, gpu, nsight

I'm trying to debug with Nsight in Visual Studio and getting "DataStackOverflow" exception on one of the function calls (call stack consist of 4 device func calls).

It says:

```
StackPointer = 0x00fff7e8 and StackLimit = 0x00fff950.
```

As Greg Smith in his comment said: Stack grows down in address.
In addition, Greg noticed that by default the compiler decides for device functions to be inline or not.

I have added `__forceinline__` keywords to my device functions. My global function receives 8 pointers to global RAM (8 * 4 = 32 bytes) + 1 int (it's < than 256 byte limit).
But now I'm getting stack overflow exception on the first non-inline function call inside global (e.g. make_float4).

Thus, why does NVCC say "your kernel is OK, you have enough resources for that", but I get this exception during runtime?

Comment: Yes, the stack grows down in address (same as most processors). All device functions are inlined on compute capability 1.x processors. For 2.x, 3.x and 5.x the compiler can choose to inline or call the function. Compute capability 2.0 was the first to add an ABI. The default compilation options are to use the ABI.

Comment: I added __forceinline__ keyword to them and thought it would help. But now stack overflow exception is caused by standard vector_types functions (like make_float4). My kernel receives a lot of parameters, but if this is a problem: why the exception didn't appear on the first device function call when I hadn't any __forceinline__ keywords?

Comment: You have not provided a reproducible. I recommend you single step the code in the CUDA debugger with mixed mode display and understand the generated code.

Comment: "Thus, why does NVCC say "your kernel is OK, you have enough resources for that","  NVCC never says that.  There are many examples on this cuda tag where folks have programs that compile just fine and then run out of resources at kernel launch time.  Compilers generally don't guarantee the correctness of code.  Asking "why does my code produce this runtime error" while providing none of your code probably won't be productive.  Voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

The GPU memory is limited, all the data and code would occupy memory space on the device. And the debug also have some overhead and consume some device memory.

you can use driver api cuMemGetInfo to get free and total memory in bytes.

if your device memory is surplus, maybe it's stacklimit is small, you can cuCtxSetLimit to set CU_LIMIT_STACK_SIZE to change stack size.

otherwise, you could try with an more powerful GPU.